# Environment variables in .erb file

Tags: ruby, dashing

I am creating a dashboard with dashing. I have some environment variables I am using in my jobs .rb file. Whenever I try to use any environment variable in my dashboard .erb file it doesnt seem to work. I am trying to put the environment variable within a url. My environment variable is #{ENV['Variable']}. Any ideas how to get environment variables to work in .erb file?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  Dashing.widget_base_dimensions = [170, 170]
  Dashing.numColumns = 10
});
</script>

<% content_for :title do %>xxxxxx<% end %>

<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="3" onClick="javascript: window.open('https://xxxxxxx.#{ENV['Variable']}.xxxxxxx.com', '_blank');">
            <div data-id="xxxxx" data-view="xxxxx" data-title="xxxxxxx" data-descriptiontitle="xxxxxxx" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What happens now?

Comment: The onClick for that widget just doesnt work

Comment: Use the browser `inspectElement` function and  paste the content of generated `onClick`. Also, check for errors in the console. Paste both in the comments (as you probably cannot edit the question)

Comment: Getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on that line

Comment: And what is in `ENV['Variable']`?

Comment: Variable is my environment variable and im trying to call it

Comment: Try: `"javascript: window.open('https://xxxxxxx.#{j(ENV['Variable'])}.xxxxxxx.com', '_blank');"` to escape variable content

Answer (score 3):

I got it. I just had to do:

```
'https://xxxxx.<%= ENV['ENVHOST'] %>.xxxxx.com/'
```